# Rails: Undefined method error with additional ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails learning coding for fun. My goal is to let a teacher see list all posts made users who have that teacher. Posts belong to users, and users belong to teachers.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :teacher
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_posts, through: :users, source: :posts

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

The teachers controller:

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_teacher, only: [:index]

def index
 @posts = @teacher.user_posts
end

private
  def find_teacher
    @teacher = current_user
  end 
end
```

I am struggling with @posts. I keep getting errors for undefined method for `user_posts'. I am wondering what I have done wrong and where to define it.

Schema.rb (just relevant parts)

```
create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "teachers", ["email"], name: "index_teachers_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "teachers", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_teachers_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "TeacherEmail"
    t.string   "teacher"
  end
```

I tried figuring this out all day yesterday and this morning and am truly stuck. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if User `belongs_to :teacher`, the schema of table `Users` should have column `teacher_id` with `integer` type.

```
t.integer "teacher_id"
```

Then if Teacher manager many users, you have to define it in Teacher model. Then you can create a method to query for all posts made by users who have that teacher:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  def user_posts
    Post.where(id: users.map(&:id))
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked in addition to what Padmanaban Gokula said! I had to reset the database after making all the changes. Thanks to everyone. This is a big milestone for me!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing user model association in teacher model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :posts, through: :users
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that strike me:

- that there's no `teacher_id` foreign key on the `users` table. You need it for `belongs_to`.
- it should be `has_many` in `Teacher` not `belongs_to` for the association with users.

Hint: after a migration, restart the server/console.